# Finding possible values for a function

Tags: inequality

After diving into simple inequalities, I've come across a particular exercise that requires me to find all possible value for $x$ for a given function. After searching about it, it seems to be simply finding the domain of the function. The question is as follows:

> If x is real, find the set of possible values of the following functions:

a) $$\frac{x+1}{2x^2+x+1}$$

b) $$\frac{1+x^2}{x}$$

---

I kindly ask to guide me through either one. I don't wish to simply have the answer thrown at me or if so, to kindly take the time to explain how you got to it. I shall continue working it and adding my attempts to the main post.

### Attempt working question a)

Worked the derivative using the quotient rule and obtained:
$$\frac{(x+1)(4x+1)}{(2x^2+x+10)^2} - \frac{1}{2x^2+x+10}$$

Comment: I think they are asking you the range, not the domain.

Comment: @YvesDaoust - It may be the case, I'm not entirely sure to be fairly honest with you.

Comment: The domain question should say "the set of values where the following functions are defined".

Comment: @YvesDaoust So it would indeed be the case of finding the range rather than domain. According to Peter, it's calculated using extremes and limits −∞ and ∞, so I'll try that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint for a) Look at the limit for f(x), x tending to $- \infty$ or $\infty$
             and at the extrema of f.

Hint for b) The function is symmetric to the origin.

Comment: Indeed, great. Thanks a million Peter for your help. Will rework these again and try finishing the exercise

Answer (score 1):

a) The denominator never cancels so this function remains bounded (the degree of the denominator exceeds that of the numerator; the $x$ axis is an asymptote).

The numerator of the derivative, $$(2x^2+x+1)-(x+1)(4x+1)=-2x^2-4x,$$ cancels for $x=0$ and $x=-2$, corresponding to two extrema.

Then $f(-2)=-\frac17$ and $f(0)=1$. These are the bounds of the range, $[-\frac17,1]$.

b) The denominator cancels for $x=0$ so that the function reaches $\pm\infty$ (it behaves like $1/x$).

The numerator of the derivative is $2x^2-(1+x^2)=x^2-1$. There are two extrema, at $x=\pm1$, with $f(-1)=-2$ and $f(1)=2$.

As $f(0^-)=-\infty$, $x=-1$ is a maximum, and conversely, $f(0^+)=\infty$ and $x=1$ is a minimum.

Hence $]-\infty,-2]\cup[2,\infty[$.

Comment: Great, managed to get here however I somewhat over=complicated the derivation that made it awkward to find the roots for. So it seem that the range would be $−∞, -\frac{1}{7}$ and $1, ∞$?

Comment: Nope, there is no way for function a to reach infinity.